# Reversing a Map but using the values as keys, and keys as values

Tags: scala

I have a map defined below.  The key represents a UserID and the value represents and AddressId.

```
val m: Map[Int, List[Int]]
```

I want to know reverse the map, meaning for every item in each List I want to make it a key, and the value be a list of keys.

So basically for every AddressID I will have a list of UserID's.

How can I do this?

I know I can use mapValues but I need to somehow refer back to the key.

Doing this won't create the list:

```
m.map(k => (k._2, k._1))
```

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular Scala

```
m
    .toVector
    .flatMap   { case (k, vs) => vs.map(_ -> k) }
    .groupBy   { case (v, _) => v }
    .mapValues { _.map { case (_, k) => k } }
```

If you're using *cats* or *Scalaz*:

```
m.toVector foldMap { case (k, vs) => vs foldMap (v => Map(v -> List(k)))  }
```

Comment: If I have a Map[Long, Set[Long]] would that change things?

Comment: @coolbreeze the regular Scala solution would work still - after `flatMap` on a `Vector` you still get a `Vector[(Long, Long)]`, but the result would be `Map[Int, List[Int]`, so you'll need a `.toSet` in `mapValues`. Scalaz/cats, IIRC, don't allow foldMap on `Set`, at least without extra dependencies at least

Answer (score 0):

Here is a potential solution:

```
val m = Map( 1 -> List("a","b"), 2 -> List("c","a" ))

val m1 = m.toList.flatMap{ case(key,valueList) => valueList.map(value => (value,key) )}.groupBy{ _._1  } 

m1.map{ case(key,valueList) => key -> valueList.map{case (x,y) => y  } }
```

Not the most elegant method but it seems to work on my side.